# NoInitialContextException after refactoring project to a new project after conflict with SVN

Tags: java, glassfish

I have an application that uses JNDI and first it worked and after I made a new project because of a conflict with SVN it now throws a NoInitialContextException.

This is the exception it throws:

> NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment
>   or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application
>   resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial

And the same kind of project of another group still works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have jndi.properties file somewhere in the class-path (you might have deleted / corrupted that file after the conflict).

This file defines the InitialContext for the JNDI bindings.